# C# How to Get a Object Attribute by String?

Tags: c#, object, attributes

I have an Object (Player) with an Attribute (Name)

```
Player player = new Player()
{
   player.Name = "testName"
}
```

And I want to get that Attribute throw a string that i got from a [CallerMemberName]:

```
private void GetAttribute([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
{
//Here the string caller is "Name"
//Isnt there a way i can do Like when i search Controls (Controls.Find(...))
//player.Find(caller);
}
string attributeString = "Name";
```

Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: `Name` is not an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/), it's a property. It's not clear how `GetAttribute` is called and what problem you have. See [mcve].

Comment: Ups, yes sry i meant Property, not Attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Reflection is what you need:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Player player = new Player();
        player.Name = "Foo";


        string valueOfName = typeof(Player).GetProperty("Name").GetValue(player).ToString();

        //valueOfName is now Foo

        typeof(Player).GetProperty("Name").SetValue(player, "Bar");
        //player.Name is now Bar
    }
}

class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thats very helpful, but not quite what I wanted, i was asking to get the Property, not the Value of that property, so that i can do player.Name = "..."; and I only have that string property = "Name" Like when i have string controlName = "textBox1" and then i do 
Controls[] control = controls.FInd(controlName, true) and then i can do control[0].enabled = false;

Comment: like this? typeof(Player).GetProperty("Name").SetValue(player, "Foo");

Comment: Sweet! Just be aware that Reflection is kinda slow.

Comment: Is there a faster way to do exactly the same?